# Center display over placemarks in selected folder

Tags: kml

I generate a tree of folders with Admin1 and Admin2, which contain placemarks.  When a folder is selected in Earth, I'd like to move to a box/altitude so that all the placemarks in that Admin level are visible.

Is there a way to do this with KML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like double clicking on the folder in Earth does exactly what I want.